# Add Dynamic Property To End of Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am creating an object and set its properties dynamically and push it to an array, as below:

```
var modelData = [];
var data = {}
data['rain'] = '123';
var items = [{name: 'prod', default_id: 1}, {name: 'dev', default_id: 2}]
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {       
   var id = items[i].name;
   data[id] = items[i].default_id;
}
modelData.push(data)
```

This works fine but by default it adds the properties in ascending order. I want it to be added to the end of the object, so my properties would be `rain, prod, dev` instead of `dev, prod, rain`

Is that possible?

see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nbegce5p/1/) console for an example.

Comment: The order of properties of an object is not guaranteed, so your question is moot I'm afraid. If you want to keep the order then you need to use an array instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects don't have a guaranteed order in JS. The closest thing you can get is an array of arrays:

```
var ordered_object = [];
ordered_object.push(['rain', 'First element']);
ordered_object.push(['prod', 'Second element']);
ordered_object.push(['dev', 'Third element']);
ordered_object.forEach(function(pair) {
    var key = pair[0],
        value = pair[1];

    console.log(key + ': ' + value);
});
```

It will be ordered, but getting the value of a "property" (they're not really properties any more) is a little more difficult:

```
function get_value(ordered_object, key) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ordered_object.length; i++) {
        if (ordered_object[i][0] === key) {
            return ordered_object[i][1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, same question:  would there be a way to create object of this array in javascript and keep the order? or do I need to replace the brackets with object bracket...I need it to be one object

Comment: @Zaki Sorry, I don't fully understand what you're asking, but if you're asking if there's a way to use objects/object notation (`{key: value}`) and still keep the order, no, there isn't.